# Transactional model update in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I previously worked with React/Mobx with the [action](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/action.html) concept. This allows to change some model properties in one transaction without firing multiple events to update UI state (only one event will be triggered after an action method will be executed).

Is there any approach or may be patterns to achieve the same behavior in Angular 2?

Comment: I think [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) explains the change detection very well. Angular2 uses rxjs a lot and I think using an Observable would be a good way to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that MobX can be used with Angular 2 as well: https://github.com/500tech/ng2-mobx

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a service like this to control UI:

```
@Injectable()
export class UIService {
  private buffer: any = {};
  private dispatcher: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.dispatcher
      .asObservable()
      .map(state => this.buffer = { ...this.buffer, ...state })
      .debounceTime(50)
      .subscribe(() => { /* do something */));
  }

  set(key: string, value?: any) {
    this.dispatcher.next({ [key]: value });
  }
}
```

and in different components in `ngOnInit()` I set different options:

```
this.uiService.set('footer', false); // in base component
this.uiService.set('footer', true); // in extended component
this.uiService.set('sidebar', true); // in other component
this.uiService.set('title', 'My Page'); // elsewhere...
```

This way I have only one object that reflects my current UI state...